# pymongo duplicate id error while running same code second time

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying pymongo first time, when I try to insert data in the collection, at first it is successfully created but when I run same script it throws id duplication error. 
I read that mongodb/pymongo itself creates unique id if we don't mention it.
I want to use auto-generation of id method which seems simple and good for heavy database(isn't it?). 
how to do that?

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

#step 1: connection

client = MongoClient(port=27017)
db=client["book"]
collection = db["book_booklist"]

#step 2: create sample data
data= {'name':'Great ideas', 'price':'100', 'Author':'gogo','issue_duration':'30'}


value= collection.insert_one(data)
print(value)
```

Error: on second try 
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: book.book_booklist index: **primary_key** dup key: { id: null }

Comment: As per `pymongo` what happens at every insert operation is that it appends a special key `_id` to the original object reference at:[Insert Document](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html?highlight=insert_one#inserting-a-document). So, it would be better to clear the `_id` key's value(*if you are trying to re-insert the same document*). More on the `null` duplicate value [MongoDB show duplicate key is null?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/211650/158423)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manually initialize and push the data along with `ObjectId` within python, every time you try to run the script.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

#step 1: connection

client = MongoClient(port=27017)
db=client["book"]
collection = db["book_booklist"]

#step 2: create sample data
data= {'_id': ObjectId(), 'name':'Great ideas', 'price':'100', 'Author':'gogo','issue_duration':'30'}


value= collection.insert_one(data)
print(value)
```

> Note: `BSON` module for python in auto-installed when you install `pymongo` package.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on vikscool's comment:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> doc = {'x':1, 'y':1, 'z':1}
>>> print(doc)
{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 1}
>>> conn.test.test.insert_one(doc)
<pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x1075a2410>
>>> print(doc)
{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 1, '_id': ObjectId('5dcb4293a6d58c694795bc9d')}
```

Note that `doc` was mutated by the `insert_one()` method. It added the `_id` field, so when you try to insert it again, it will complain about duplicate `_id`.